# How can i check if the value of a cell matches another right next to it?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Sorry i didnt know exactly how to word it, but basically im checking a list of names for a match. i have one cell set up so it checks the last name of a person and if the last name matches, it should then jump to the next column and check to see if the first name matches as well.

heres a basic summary

if the same last name comes up, but a different first name, no match

if a different last name comes up, but the same first name, no match

if both the first name and the last name are the same, match.

any suggestions?

Comment: So you have one name, and you want to see if there is a match in another column of names?

Comment: What is the structure of your spreadsheet? Do you have two last name columns and two first name columns?

Comment: in column A is last names, in column b is first names, in column c is last name check, and in column d is first name check on the match sheet. on a second sheet is the reference list that its comparing the names to

Comment: So you have the match logic - which returns a true into `c` if the last names match and returns a true into `d` if the first names match?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it based on what you have described.

If you have your Last Names set up in Column A and your First Names in Column B and have separate cells for entering a First Name and a Last Name to check (in this example, First Name check = C1, Last Name check = D1) enter the following in any cell to show the results of the test:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,C1)>0,IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,C1)>1,"Multiple Matches","Match exists"),"No matches")
```

From here you can modify accordingly, but the above will also alert you as to if more than one match exists.

Cheers.

**::Point of Clarification Edit Below::**

So I'm completely clear on how I interpreted your question, the above solution will serve as a search through two adjacent columns of information to see if a match exists for your search criteria entered in cells C1 and D1.  My response is just one of many ways to handle a search like this.  If not exactly what you were looking for, I hope it points you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks guys! I ended up solving it with an array MATCH checking the names combined (last name and first name in the same cell) it works!

Comment: You're welcome.  I suspected that things might be a bit more simple but it was difficult to tell without an example layout of your data.  Good luck out there. Cheers!